# How can I convert row names in multiple data frames to column in data frame>

Tags: r, dataframe, r-rownames

I have a list of `.csv` files that I have read in to R and placed in a large data frame called `data` that consists of 6 data.frames which are the 6 files in `filenames`. My code so far is:

```
filenames <- list.files( paste(mainDirInput,sep=""), pattern="Out.*csv", full.names=TRUE) 
data = lapply(filenames, function(f) {
wb = read.csv(f, header=TRUE)
})
```

The row names and column names in each data.frame are exactly the same, I would like to extract the row names and instead have them as the first column in R. An example of one of my data frames would be like this:

```
            w    x    y    z
2012 01     12   43   87   09
2012 02     14   53   75   76
2012 03     76   34   76   28
2012 04     41   36   85   16
  :         :    :    :    :
  :         :    :    :    :
```

I need to be able to use this code on other files as well, so I can't simply just create a new column with the values `2012 01, 2012 02, 2012 03...`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Youve got a `dataframe` with columns named "w,x,y,z" . Just do

```
data$names <- rownames(data)
```

to add a new column.

#### edit

In response to Boogie's query, here's `lapply` with an anonymous function to do the loop.

```
   foo = as.data.frame(matrix(1:15,3,5))
    rownames(foo) <-c('frist','prime','lastly')
    foo
    bar = list(foo,t(foo), rbind(foo,foo))
    bar[[1]] = as.data.frame( foo)
    bar[[2]] =data.frame( t(foo))
    bar[[3]] = data.frame(rbind(foo,foo))
    bar
    bar = lapply(bar,FUN= function(x) { x$date <-rownames(x);return(x)})
    bar
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for my individual data.frames, so it works if I apply it to `data[[1]]$names<-rownames(data[[1]])` but `data` is a list of 6 individual data.frames, I'm looking to find a way to apply something similar to what you have given me but to all of my data.frames in `data`.

Comment: Oh, this works if I apply it in a for loop! `for (k in 1:length(data)){
data[[k]]$date <- rownames(data[[k]]) }` Thank you for your help

Comment: Is there a way to do this with `lapply()`, not just a for loop?

Comment: @Boogi pretty much any `for` loop can be made into a `*apply` call.  In this case you may need an anonymous function defined.  See my edits for an example