# How can I convert row names into the first column?

Tags: r, dataframe, col, r-rownames

I have a data frame like this:

```
df
              VALUE              ABS_CALL DETECTION P-VALUE    
    1007_s_at "957.729231881542" "P"      "0.00486279317241156"
    1053_at   "320.632701283368" "P"      "0.0313356324173416" 
    117_at    "429.842323161046" "P"      "0.0170004527476119" 
    121_at    "2395.7364289242"  "P"      "0.0114473584876183" 
    1255_g_at "116.493632746934" "A"      "0.39799368200131"   
    1294_at   "739.927122116896" "A"      "0.0668649772942343"
```

I want to convert the row names into the first column. Currently I use something  like this to make row names as the first column:

```
  d <- df
  names <- rownames(d)
  rownames(d) <- NULL
  data <- cbind(names,d)
```

Is there a single line to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [R: converting row names in multiple data frames to column in data frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18403199/r-converting-row-names-in-multiple-data-frames-to-column-in-data-frame)

Comment: You don't need extra packages, here's a one-liner: `d <- cbind(rownames(d), data.frame(d, row.names=NULL))`

Comment: The comment by @ssp3nc3r should be an accepted answer

Comment: Even easier: ```d$names <- rownames(d)```

Answer (score 242, accepted):

Or you can use `tibble`'s `rownames_to_column` which does the same thing as David's answer:

```
library(tibble)
df <- tibble::rownames_to_column(df, "VALUE")
```

Note: The earlier function called `add_rownames()` has been deprecated and is being replaced by `tibble::rownames_to_column()`

Comment: Not *exactly* the same, because it's not doing it *by reference* :)

Comment: UPDATE: dplyr update requires one to use tibble::rownames_to_column() since dplyr::rownames is deprecated.

Comment: This is great if one wants to stay within the tidyverse

Answer (score 164):

You can *both* remove row names and convert them to a column *by reference* (without reallocating memory using `->`) using `setDT` and its `keep.rownames = TRUE` argument from the `data.table` package

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df, keep.rownames = TRUE)[]
#    rn     VALUE  ABS_CALL DETECTION     P.VALUE
# 1:  1 1007_s_at  957.7292         P 0.004862793
# 2:  2   1053_at  320.6327         P 0.031335632
# 3:  3    117_at  429.8423         P 0.017000453
# 4:  4    121_at 2395.7364         P 0.011447358
# 5:  5 1255_g_at  116.4936         A 0.397993682
# 6:  6   1294_at  739.9271         A 0.066864977
```

As mentioned by @snoram, you can give the new column any name you want, e.g. `setDT(df, keep.rownames = "newname")` would add "newname" as the rows column.

Comment: Use ``colnames(df)[1] <- "newname"`` to rename the first column if needed.

Comment: @Swetabh Well, no. `setnames(df, 1, "newname")` is the `data.table` way.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Well, (at least) now you can do it in the same call `setDT(df, keep.rownames = "newname")[]`

Comment: @snoram to do what at the same call?

Comment: @DavidArenburg setting the name from within the `setDT()` call - no need for `setnames()`

Comment: @snoram Interesting, I haven't seen it documented anywhere

Comment: @DavidArenburg found in documentation for `as.data.table()`: *If TRUE, adds the input object's names as a separate column named "rn". keep.rownames = "id" names the column "id" instead*

Comment: @snoram good find, I'll make a PR  regarding that to make docs consistent.

Answer (score 121):

A one line option is :

```
df$names <- rownames(df)
```

Comment: I hope you are aware of the fact that it adds `rownames` as a column at the last, indeed not as a first column.

Comment: After to remove index use `rownames(df) <- NULL`

Comment: @vasili111 - could you explain what does it mean by 'to remove index' as I see no difference to the data table before (df$names <- rownames(df)) and after (rownames(df) <- NULL). Do you mean it stores the index column internally?

Comment: @AravindanKalai Hi. `rownames(df) <- NULL` will remove original row names. I was referring to row names.

Answer (score 40):

Alternatively, you can create a new dataframe (or overwrite the current one, as the example below) so you do not need to use of any external package. However this way may not be efficient with huge dataframes.

```
df <- data.frame(names = row.names(df), df)
```

Comment: Or: `df <- cbind(names = rownames(df), df)`

Answer (score 33):

Moved my comment into an answer per suggestion above:

You don't need extra packages, here's a one-liner:

```
d <- cbind(rownames(d), data.frame(d, row.names=NULL))
```

Answer (score 9):

`dplyr::as_tibble(df, rownames = "your_row_name")` will give you even simpler result.

Comment: @HectorHaffenden have edited this for the poster, because it's actually a nice suggestion.

Comment: "`as_data_frame()` was deprecated in tibble 2.0.0.
Please use `as_tibble()` instead." Otherwise this is my favourite.

Answer (score 6):

## Change data rownames as a real column

```
data <- data %>%
  rownames_to_column(var="the name you want")
```

Answer (score 4):

```
df = data.frame(columnNameILike = row.names(df), df, row.names=NULL)
```

Answer (score 3):

Or by using `DBI`s `sqlRownamesToColumn`

```
library(DBI)
sqlRownamesToColumn(df)
```