# How to shift index into "recognisable format" in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, raster

I have a dataframe that looks like this, and would like to convert the left-most column into an actual index, with the label "id".

[image: Dataframe]

I tried to rename it with colnames<- but it didn't work, as ncol() only returns 2.
I tried to export it as a csv file, but index was similarly not captured in the file.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't upload code or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert row names into first column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29511215/convert-row-names-into-first-column)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to do this. Firstly, the method you used to write to csv you can also include the `row.names = TRUE` parameter in the `write.csv` function. Otherwise, the following commands also work:

```
library(tibble)
df <- tibble::rownames_to_column(df, "VALUE")
```

(taken from [Convert row names into first column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29511215/convert-row-names-into-first-column))

Answer (score 0):

Example data

```
d <- data.frame(layer=2:4, gridpop=c(1000,2000,3000))
rownames(d) <- c("A", "B", "C")
d
#  layer gridpop
#A     2    1000
#B     3    2000
#C     4    3000
```

Solution

```
d$id <- rownames(d)
d
#  layer gridpop id
#A     2    1000  A
#B     3    2000  B
#C     4    3000  C
```

Or if the row names represent numbers

```
d$id <- as.numeric(rownames(d))
```