# Rownames as column in list of dataframes

Tags: r, list, r-rownames

I'd like to create a column *year* for each dataframe in a list based on its rownames. This question [has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18403199/convert-row-names-in-multiple-data-frames-to-column-in-data-frame) on SO but unfortunately the answer doesn't help. So, *is* there a way to do it?

```
mylist <- list(structure(list(a = 1:10), .Names = "a", row.names = 1991:2000, class = "data.frame"), 
            structure(list(a = 1:10), .Names = "a", row.names = 1992:2001, class = "data.frame"))
```

Expected outcome:

```
[[1]]
      a year
1991  1 1991
1992  2 1992
1993  3 1993
1994  4 1994
1995  5 1995
1996  6 1996
1997  7 1997
1998  8 1998
1999  9 1999
2000 10 2000

[[2]]
      a year
1992  1 1992
1993  2 1993
1994  3 1994
1995  4 1995
1996  5 1996
1997  6 1997
1998  7 1998
1999  8 1999
2000  9 2000
2001 10 2001
```

Comment: Why doesn't it help? What question are you referencing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `Map`

```
Map(cbind, mylist, year= lapply(mylist, rownames))
```

Comment: I guess your original answer with `Map` + `lapply` will be less efficient

Comment: @docendodiscimus I didn't see that you posted a similar answer.  I will delete it.

Answer (score 5):

Here's another option:

```
lapply(mylist, function(df) transform(df, year = rownames(df)))
```

Just for fun, you could also use dplyr's `add_rownames` function:

```
lapply(mylist, dplyr::add_rownames, 'year')
```