# request for adding new column in R

Tags: r, insert

in R I have in mydata data frame which column names is gene id and row names are sample id:

```
             ENSG00000000003   ENSG00000000004  ENSG00000000005
TCGA-QQ-A5VB       0.1               0.2              0.3
TCGA-DX-A8BO       0.3               0.1              0.2
TCGA-MO-A47R       0.3               0.1              0.2
```

Now I want to have a sample_ID column that valus are rownames(mydata) and add a column x before sample_ID column. also I want to insert rownames just by numbering same as below:

```
     x       Sample_ID    ENSG00000000003   ENSG00000000004  ENSG00000000005
1    1      TCGA-QQ-A5VB        0.1               0.2              0.3 
2    2      TCGA-DX-A8BO        0.3               0.1              0.2
3    3      TCGA-MO-A47R        0.3               0.1              0.2
```

I have to say mydata file has 56000 genes as colnames and the position of columns x and sample_ID are important. I don't want to have these columns in the end of columns.

I appreciate if anybody share his/her comment as code with me.

Best Regards,

Mohammad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly a duplicated issue: [Convert row names in multiple data frames to column in data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18403199/convert-row-names-in-multiple-data-frames-to-column-in-data-frame)

I hope this helps:

```
data <- data.frame(x = 1:nrow(data), Sample_ID = row.names(data), data)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks.one more question. if I want add these 2 column in end of mydata columns. how can I do?

Comment: Hi. You just put them attention the end of the Data.frame call `data.frame(data, x = 1:nrow(data), Sample_ID = row.names(data))`